# AWS IOT limit of creating things

Tags: aws-iot

Is there a limit that per time we can create some particular number of things in AWS IOT? I have a requirement to create 10,000 of things in aws iot. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit for the `CreateThing` API is 15 requests per second. This limit is adjustable if you reach out to AWS customer support.

[AWS IoT limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html)